# Bootstrap affixed sidebar being overlapped by main content in Angular app

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an angular app with some nested views that might be causing the problem but I just can't pin it down. Whenever `position: fixed` is added to the sidebar the main content moves over and overlaps it. You can see whats happening at [this page](http://test.codebyjordan.com/#/products/products/juice) and here is some of my code, let me know if more is needed.

***Update**
I tried combining the app.products and app.products.juice states and I still have the issue so I'm thinking it's my CSS and not the nested states

**Controller**

```
.controller('ProductsCtrl', function() {
    $('#affix').affix({
      offset: {
        top: function () {
              var $el = $('#productsBg');
              return (this.top = $el.position().top + $el.outerHeight(true));
            },
        bottom: 50
      }
    })
  })
```

**SCSS**

```
.ui-view-container {
  position: relative;
}
.panelNav {
  margin: 5% 0 0 5%;
  &.affix {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

**State app**

```
<header>
...
</header>

<div class="ui-view-container">
  <main ui-view="mainContent"></main>
</div>

<footer id="footer">

</footer>
```

**State app.products**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id=affix class="col-md-2 panelNav">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">

      <div class="panel-heading">Products Menu</div>

      <div class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item" ui-sref="app.products.juice">Juice</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" ui-sref="app.products.mods">Mods</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" ui-sref="app.products.batteries">Batteries</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" ui-sref="app.products.tanks">Tanks</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="col-md-9">
    <ui-view name="productsContent"></ui-view>
  </section>
</div>
```

**State app.products.juice**

```
<div>
  <p> 10 paragraphs of filler text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update Jun 2017: As noted by [@AdamPlocher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/730566/adam-plocher) my original suggestion below didn't clearly answer the question, here's a better illustration:

https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/ZyOOdM

====
Original answer

See if this helps you :http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/EKGXGj

When you apply `position: fixed;` to the sidebar, it takes it out of flow, and the main content moves to the left, into the space which had been occupied by the sidebar.

One option which I think should work for you is to leave the sidebar unchanged, and instead create a new child div and apply `position:fixed;` to this child div.  (see below)

When you do this, the sidebar stays in-flow, doesn't collapse and the main content doesn't move left.

Hope this helps!

=== CSS ===

```
.panelNav{
  position:absolute;
}
```

=== Original HTML ===

```
<div class="container-fluid original">
   <div class="col-md-2 sidebar panelNav">sidebar</div>
   <div class="col-md-9 main-content">main content</div>
</div>
```

=== Updated HTML ===

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
      <div class="panelNav">sidebar</div>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 main-content">main content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This stopped the content overlapping the sidebar. The sidebar would shrink though but nothing a little extra css couldn't fix. Thanks again!

Comment: There's nothing 'fixed' in your example?? -1

Comment: haha @AdamPlocher you are correct, not sure what happened there.  I guess the important bit is that I was trying to show how to take panelNav out of normal flow without the sidebar collapsing. Maybe this is closer to what you were expecting to see: https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/QgNqRK

Comment: @DavidTaiaroa lol thank you, undownvote and a +1 to you good sir.  Now I feel like your answer touches on the question that (at least what I got out of it) was asked :).  Sorry for the threadjack, but the problem I have with just about any "fixed" solution is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487529/using-angular-ui-bootstrap-and-a-fixed-sidebar which can be seen in your example too: https://codepen.io/aplocher/pen/QgENNR - notice how the text overflows when fixed, cannot figure out a way to accurately determine the width of the parent and cause it to wrap - not without JS I guess.

Comment: no problem @AdamPlocher, see if this helps: https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/ZyOOdM

Comment: @AdamPlocher, https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/ZyOOdM is better now, it was incomplete earlier