# Using angular-ui-bootstrap and a fixed sidebar

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I've seen several examples of using bootstrap ScrollSpy / Affix, but I'm having a hard time applying that to angular-ui-bootstrap.  I would like to have a left-sidebar on my UI, that is fixed (it's position remains even when the rest of the page is scrolling).

I have two plnkr's.  One shows a non-fixed (but mostly functional) sidebar, the other shows an ALMOST working fixed sidebar - but the content pushes the width out further than it should.  In the second example, if I could figure out how to constrain the width to the parent width, it would work how I want:

Static sidebar: http://plnkr.co/edit/A1kyi1?p=preview

position:fixed (but width is pushed out too far) sidebar: http://plnkr.co/edit/R11BFt?p=preview

Here is the important code:

```
  <div class="container pull-left">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 sidebar" style="background-color:blue;">
        <div style="background-color:orange;">
          Some side bar stuff
          <br />
          <br /> Some side bar stuff
          <br />
          <br /> Some side bar stuff
          <br />
          <br /> Some side bar stuff
          <br />
          <br /> Some side bar stuff
          <br />
          <br /> Something that pushes the width out.  Something that pushes the width out....    
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9" style="background-color:#eeeeee;">
        <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox
          jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy
          dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown
          fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the
          lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
        </p>
```

css:

```
.sidebar > div {  position: fixed; z-index:10000; top:50px;left:0;}
```

Screenshot:[image]

Does anyone know how I can get this working? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adam, try adding a width to your the element that's fixed, eg

```
.sidebar > div {  position: fixed; z-index:10000; top:50px;left:0; width:200px;}
```

**Update**:
Here's a refinement which uses native Bootstrap classes and a few media queries to manage the sidebar width:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/zzBZzV

Comment: Hello again David, thank you for your reply. The problem I'm trying to solve is I would like it to use dynamic/relative widths by using the Bootstrap grid system. The sidebar container is .col-md-3 which would be similar to width:25% of the grid (I think). Hardcoding a width kinda works, but it also kinda defeats the purpose of keeping it in the grid. I would like to keep everything sizing right at any screen width with the sidebar container.  I could use media queries to size it to an absolute width at 100px intervals or something, but ... that seems pretty hacky :-/

Comment: @AdamPlocher, check out https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/ZyOOdM now, I'll post a similar solution for this thread when I get a chance

Comment: Thanks David, that's very interesting.  I was playing with position:relative containers for fixed and for the life of me, I couldn't get it to work. It seems by NOT specifying a top,left,right,or bottom on the fixed element, it allows it to be relative to the parent.  As soon as I specify that, it breaks.  This might be the solution I need.  I'm going to try to put this in my solution and see if any other "gotchas" pop up...  Will let you know shortly, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.sidebar-fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-3 sidebar-fixed">Side bar content</div>
<div class="col-md-9">Main Content</div>
```